# R Hadoop Memory issue

Tags: out-of-memory, rhadoop

I am trying to run a distributed implementation of kmeans clustering on hadoop with rmr2 (on a single-machine cluster with Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.2 in pseduo-distributed mode). As long as the data file size (on HDFS) is small (around 1000 data points) it's working fine.

But as I increase the number of points to 5000 points which is still pretty small (the size of the data file is only ~1MB) it starts throwing errors as follows:

container_1473314686409_0005_01_000006 is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 3.2 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.

I have already tried the following from some other post, but it has no impact:

```
rmr.options(backend.parameters = 
  list(
    hadoop = 
      list(
        D = "mapred.map.memory.mb=2048",
        D = "mapred.reduce.memory.mb=2048",           
        D = "mapred.map.java.opts=-Xmx400M",
        D = "mapred.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx400M"
    )
   )
```

> My OS version is: Linux quickstart.cloudera 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1
>   SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

First of all I am not understanding why it requires > 1G memory to process a small file.

Secondly, I want to scale the implementation to huge datasets (at least for a few GB). How can I do that?

Finally, I am finding that most if not all R-hadoop posts are quite old, have the people stopped working on R-hadoop after 2014? Is Spark-R a better option?

Any help along these lines will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcme to SO! It'd be nice if you formatted your question a bit, so it's more clear and readable! Make code look like code etc. ;)

Comment: @iScrE4m thanks, will do.

Comment: @Atf: thanks for formatting the post.

Comment: Welcome bro @sandipan